# TracD / Python on Windows 8

Tags: python, windows-8, sqlite, trac

Background:

Upgrading development environment to Windows 8 (x64) with clean install.  Trac/Python setup is identical to long established working and reliable implementation under Windows 7 (x64).

Trac 1.0, ActivePython 2.7.2 (x86) using TracD as service with SVRANY (problems are identical with test of TracD in administrator Command Prompt instead of as service).

Symptoms:

Display of Trac elements erratic in browser - missing style and layout from time to time, some images fail to appear but can be loaded by right-click Show Picture.  After a short time, Trac site becomes inaccessible and the service has to be restarted.  Problem occurs with IE10 and Chrome (not browser related, see below).

Log:

An error is generated many times on each page access (TracD):

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
self.wfile.flush()
self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in
your host machine
File "C:-\Pyt-h-o-n2-7\-l---i----b-\--so-ck--e--t.-p--y-"-,-- ---line 303,- --
-i---n-- flush
```

Event Log:

More rarely, another problem is occurring:

```
Faulting application name: Python.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4e04e3b8
Faulting module name: sqlite3.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4e04e486
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00014c45
Faulting process id: 0x638
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce039b9e7bf067
Faulting application path: C:\Python27\Python.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Python27\DLLs\sqlite3.dll
Report Id: 57f144f2-6f8f-11e2-bea0-00221597cbcd
```

Attempts to solve (none successful):

1. Compatibility settings.
2. Firewall temporary disable.
3. Antivirus temporary disable.
4. Google error messages and/or Trac/Python issues on Windows 8/2012.
5. Upgrade from ActivePython 2.7.2 to python.org 2.7.3 (Trac cannot run on 3.x at this time).
6. Replace TracD with Apache using Bitnami Trac Stack.
7. Ensure SQLite binaries included with Python are the latest version (not yet attempted).

Questions:

1. Has anyone got Trac/Python working correctly on Windows 8/2012 platform?
2. Is this indicative that Python 2.7.x is broken on Windows 8, with potential consequences for many applications, not just Trac, but anything running on Python using sockets or SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I doubt this problem is caused by Trac itself.